# How does one for filter for parent child documents that do not have a child document with a given attribute?

Tags: solr

I've tried these commands:

`{!parent which=type:parent v="(+type:child +event_title:*zz*)" }`
returns 103 documents

`{!parent which=type:parent v="(+type:child -event_title:*zz*)" }`
returns all documents

Total documents are 7000.  I am expecting the second query with `-event_title` to return 
7000-103 = 6897 documents.

However the `-event_title` returns all documents.  How can I just return parent documents that do not have a child document with a given attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Block join is one-to-many. It is entirely possible that `number of(+A +B) + number of(+A -B) > number of (+A)`, because one parent can have one `+A +B` child and one `+A -B` child, contributing to all three counters.

Maybe it's just the case? Imagine that every parent has at least one chid without `event_title:*zz*`, and 103 parents has also children with `event_title:*zz*`.